# Pass value of combobox as field

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

Apologies if I have the wrong terminology. I am trying to build a form where the user selects the field from a dropdown and then enters search text into a text box. The form should then search the table for records that match the text in the field specified in the combobox.

However what I currently have is not working. I know where the error is but cannot fix it.

The current code is:

```
Private Sub btn_Search_Click()

Dim strSearchTerm As String
Dim strComboField As String

strComboField = Me!cmb_src

strSearchTerm = "SELECT Models.ID, Models.[Model Name], Models.[Model Brand], Models.[Model Category] " _
    & "FROM Models " _
    & "Where Fields(strComboField) LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY Models.[Model Name]; "

Me.sub_ModelList.Form.RecordSource = strSearchTerm
Me.sub_ModelList.Form.Requery
```

End Sub

I believe the error is in the line

```
 & "Where Fields(strComboField) LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' " _
```

As replacing Fields(strComboField) with a field name [Model Name] resolves fine.

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: try `& "Where Fields " & strComboField & " LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' " _` . However, I am not sure it's the only error you have, does `strComboField` gets a value, this is not the way to read from a Combo-Box or a List-Box

Comment: thank you, that didn't work, but as you say may be because of the way I am reading from the combobox incorrectly. I will see if I can solve that. he error that gave me was (missing operator0 in query expression 'Fields Model Name LIKE '*joystick*".

Comment: when you run the code with F8, does `strComboField` reading the value correctly from the user-form combo-box ? is it a combo-box, list-box or a text ?

Comment: it's a combobox and yes, it does seem to read the value of the combobox correctly and set the variable to that value

Comment: try `& "Where Fields [" & strComboField & "] LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' ""_`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
strSearchTerm = "SELECT Models.ID, Models.[Model Name], Models.[Model Brand], Models.[Model Category] " _
    & "FROM Models " _
    & "Where [" & strComboField & "] LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY Models.[Model Name]; "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
"Where [Model Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' " _
```

or just create base query with WHERE like this:

```
Where [Model Name] LIKE '* & Forms![frm_YourForm]![cmb_src]  & *'
```

and requery the form by click on Search button, the rest of VBA code not required

**UPDATE:** sorry, missed the point about selecting the field for search. In this case WHERE should be

```
"Where [" & strComboField & "] LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' "
```

After

```
Me.sub_ModelList.Form.RecordSource = strSearchTerm
```

additional Requery not required, changing Recodsource automatically requeries the form

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I want to happen? The [Model Name] should be set by the user via a combo box to either [Model Name] OR [Model Brand] or [Model Category]. The text that the search is based on is in a text box called txtsearch. What I'm trying to so is search for me.txtbox in the field specified in the combo box.

Comment: I apologize, missed the point about selecting the field for search, second answer was correct